# What reasons do pro-trade politicians use to justify retaliatory tariffs?

Tags: economy, international-relations, trade

The general "neoliberal" position towards trade is that it benefits both sides and low tariffs/subsidies are beneficial. This has been the dominant trend in wealthy nations for the last thirty plus years, with free trade agreements and descending tariffs.

[image]

Recently, however, [politicians](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/06/10/business/trump-trade-tariffs.html) have been more inclined to impose tariffs. When Donald Trump threatened to, or actually imposed tariffs, I noticed that [other countries](http://time.com/5302836/eu-retaliatory-tariffs/) respond with threats of their [own tariffs](http://www.startribune.com/canada-s-tariff-retaliation-has-35m-price-tag-for-minnesota/484982911/). These politicians could all be closet anti-globalists who just wanted an excuse to throw up trade barriers, but I'm not interested in that side of things. My question is, what reasons do pro-globalization and pro-free-trade politicians use to justify retaliatory tariffs? The default, expected, free-trade position being [something like](https://www.fraserinstitute.org/article/everyone-loses-trade-war):

> Yet, in view of recent United States actions[tariffs], Canadian
>   nationalists may well step up their demands that Canada exercise its
>   sovereignty, raise new trade barriers, particularly against the United
>   States, and, in general, ignore international agreements. That's about
>   the silliest thing we could, something that would spell economic ruin
>   for hundreds of thousands of Canadian workers.

I'm not looking for why any politician would impose a tariff, that's been [covered elswhere](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/30968/why-is-globalisation-so-disdained), I'm looking for how politicians that believe in free trade justify retaliatory tariffs.

Comment: Comments deleted. Please don't try to answer the question with comments. If you would like to answer, please write an answer which adheres to our quality standards.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The tariffs that the EU and China have imposed on the US are politically aimed at (swing) states held by (key) Republican politicians.  In this way, the EU hopes to influence the US domestic political debate in favour of removing the tariffs, while keeping direct economic damage to a minimum.  In case of EU tariffs, [BBC News reports](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-43926092):

> Brussels said it planned to introduce retaliatory tariffs on items such as Harley-Davidson motorbikes and bourbon whiskey.

(...)

> But why exactly has Brussels chosen such specific products, and do past trade wars between the US and Europe suggest that the White House will now ultimately back down?

(...)

> Meredith Crowley, international trade economist at the University of Cambridge, says that the EU is being far more politically savvy than just picking famous American goods. Instead it has chosen products made in states that are home to some key members of Trump's Republican Party.
>
> "Bourbon is produced in Kentucky, home state of Mitch McConnell US Senate Majority Leader," she says.
>
> "Harley-Davidsons are manufactured in Wisconsin, a swing state that is the home of the Speaker of the House Paul Ryan.
>
> "The EU hopes these men will petition the president to save jobs in their home states by eliminating the US steel and aluminium tariffs."
>
> Stephen Woolcock, a lecturer in economic relations at the London School of Economics, adds that the aim is "to have as much impact [as possible] on the policy debate in Washington".

And in case of Chinese tariffs, [Sinologist Andy Rothman reports](https://matthewsasia.com/perspectives-on-asia/sinology/article-1362/default.fs):

> China will clearly retaliate with reciprocal tariffs on U.S. goods, with a list designed to inflict pain on Trump supporters, which could help Democrats take control of the House in November. Of the 2,742 counties with employment in the industries targeted by Beijing's retaliation list, 82% of those counties voted for Trump in 2016, while just 18% voted for Hillary Clinton, according to analysis by the Brookings Institution.
>
> Soybeans are high on China's retaliation list, and it is worth noting that 24 Republican Members of Congress represent districts which account for about 60% of the total U.S. soybean crop.

Comment: I don't have a source ready, but Mexico and Canada have a similar motivation for the products they tariff.

Comment: "the EU hopes to influence the US domestic political debate".  What's the argument for this being acceptable considering the whole Russia thing?

Comment: @DavidStarkey That is an entirely different question and a good one to put to the likes of Guy Verhofstadt.  I wonder if any journalist has done so yet!

Comment: @DavidStarkey Operating within established norms, laws, and trade agreements is generally regarded as "acceptable."

Comment: @BurnsBA I don't follow politics in depth, so all I know is the complaints seemed to be "Russia was trying to influence our politics".  So, seeing the EU do a similar thing made me wonder if they had a reasonable excuse.

Comment: @DavidStarkey the main difference would be that the EU's trade tariffs are openly attributable to the EU and visible to the electorate. Russian influence in recent elections is hidden behind anonymous bots and cash donations.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 42):

The point of retaliatory tariffs is to act as a disincentive to countries thinking of imposing tariffs. WTO rules, being agreements between sovereign nations, can't really be enforced. Instead they are a set of rules that set out what countries can and should do, and what responses are allowed.

Those rules allow that, in the case that an invalid tariff is imposed, other countries can (and should)  impose retaliatory tariffs so that the original offender looses more than it gains economically. The point isn't "yay, now we're free to impose the tariffs we've always wanted to under the justification of retaliation",  but rather "we're imposing these tariffs as a necessary evil so that you will see sense and remove your unfairly imposed tariffs"

The goal is to get back to a no tariff situation.

If no retaliatory tariffs were imposed, there would be no incentive for the original offender to remove their tariffs.

(and since most tariffs are imposed for reasons of domestic politics as much as economics, the retaliatory tariffs are usually designed to negate the political benefits to by e.g. targeting specific economic sectors based on voting demographics).

Comment: The incentive to remove the tariff is that the tariffs cause harm to the people of the tariff-imposing nation. Causing more harm to your own citizens, because they caused harm to theirs, is not justifiable as an incentive (or at least one's own citizens should be crying foul at such behavior). At best one could claim that it undermines the populist rhetoric of the tariff-imposer, but that is poor justification for self-harm.

Comment: @pluckedkiwi It is a gambit, in that the _threat_ of retaliatory tariffs may be enough to keep from having anything to retaliate for. In the case that the threat is ignored, most countries will still follow through with it or otherwise risk having their threats ignored in the future, or to try to persuade the original country to reconsider their actions. Without the retaliation, there is no leverage to negotiate with.

Comment: @pluckedkiwi: In addition, most retaliatory tariffs are intended to be short-lived, and thus create only short-term hardship.  Some country X imposes a tariff on country Y, causing mild hardship to company's citizens.  If company Y does nothing, its citizens will have to ensure that hardship indefinitely.  If Y response with a retaliatory tariff that causes X to back down, such action may momentarily cause more hardship to Y's citizens than X's tariff did, but will free Y of the continuing hardship that X's tariff would have imposed.

Comment: Is something missing after "a set of"?

Comment: @pluckedkiwi That harm *should* be an incentive to remove the tariff (or not impose it in the first place), but since the tariff was imposed the administration obviously doesn't care about that. So an additional incentive is needed.

Comment: So, basically, it's game theory? In the prisoner's dilemma, it's advantageous for both parties to cooperate. However, if it's known that one is *always* cooperating, *no matter what*, then the other one is incentivized to defect. So even if you do want to cooperate, you have to sometimes show that you are able and willing to defect if really pushed into it.

Comment: @vsz It's amazing how many area's of life are a Prisoner's Dilemma.

Comment: @vsz No, because that would imply that the second country benefits from imposing retaliatory tariffs. They do not. At best it gives cover to the second politician to engage in corrupt political practices for their own self-serving motivations at the cost to their countrymen as a whole. The first mover is only political cover for the 'retaliatory' action which would otherwise be seen as corrupt protectionism.

Comment: I don't think that the sort of tarrifs being imposed by the EU are particularly damaging to the EU.  If people can't buy Harleys or Bourbon they will just buy different motorcycles and booze by and large.  It's a lot more difficult to come up with an alternative to steel or aluminium.

Answer (score 6):

The nature of retaliatory tariffs is that they're used in retaliation for illegal or otherwise objectionable tariffs.  They're meant as a corrective measure to encourage the removal of the offending tariffs.  As such the differ significantly from protectionist tariffs in that they're not designed to protect domestic industries but harm those in the offending nation.  They're often put on goods that have little or no domestic production to protect.

For example while Trump's recent steel and aluminum tariffs are meant to protect domestic producers, Canada's list of retaliatory tariffs cover not just steel and aluminum, but a wide range of different products. At first glance the full list looks bizarre and random, but they can usually be be connected with particular swing state (eg. orange juice) or Republican congressional district (eg. [beer kegs](http://nationalpost.com/news/politics/inflatable-boats-felt-pens-and-beer-kegs-heres-what-canada-targeted-with-tariffs-and-why)). Mexico and the European Union have drawn up similar lists designed to maximize the political pain on Republican politicians in the US.

Now a true *laissez-faire* free trader will tell you any tariff is bad, and a country is better off never imposing them even in retaliation, but there's few people like this actually leading countries.

Comment: They are not just for retaliation.  If Country A imposes a tariff on Country B, and B does not retaliate, then A has an incentive to try yet another tariff.
Trump has imposed steel and aluminum tariffs.  If Canada had not retaliated, then Trump could say "hey, that was easy, let's go after pork (or whatever) next".

Comment: @Flydog57 or lets go after Canadian manufactured cars, as he said in his tweet " Based on Justin’s false statements at his news conference, and the fact that Canada is charging massive Tariffs ... I have instructed our U.S. Reps not to endorse the Communique as we look at Tariffs on automobiles flooding the U.S. Market!"